# Отправка сообщения о поиске IE компоненте

Tags: delphi

Delphi xe 10.
Форма. на ней - Ie компонент и кнопка.

Запускаем, ок все работает.

Вопрос.

как, при нажатии кнопки активировать окно "поиск" в IE.

доп. если запускаем форму, (важно - курсор переводим на окно IE) там жмем ctrl+f - получаем стд. окно поиска в IE (ну и поиск по окну).

т.е. нужно без получения фокуса на окне IE вызвать в нем поиск (ну т.е. стд. окно поиска).

доп. - заранее или перем. поиск, т.е. без вызова окна.

++ ну как "супер" - по второй кнопе найти что искали (например е.2 кнопка с "кодом" найти "текст", при нажатии - было бы то что и при поиске - текст смещается в окне, "текст" подсвечивается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ieComponent.SetFocus();
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), 0, 0);
keybd_event(Ord('F'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('F'), 0), 0, 0);
keybd_event(Ord('F'), MapVirtualKey(Ord('F'), 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL, MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, 0), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
// и так далее
```

Comment: большое спасибо! за ответ. проверить пока не могу, но думаю, что правильно. это ответ на основной вопрос, и я помечу как ответ, если никто не против (когда затестю). +а как быть с кнопкой2? когда знаем что искать? вариант выше, думаю не подойдет. + раздумья: а если в этот момент была кл. нажата другая? Ну например клава переносная и упала в сумку, где зациклена была на как. клавишу?

Comment: + т.е. понимаю так, что кроме как отправкой клавиш, больше никак не повлитять ?